# How to change the precision in R above 50 decimal places

Tags: python, r, precision

I have a program that makes a iterative calculation but if my precision is not good, the calculation stops very fast. So, I have to get a better precision.

I already have the same program in Python, and in this language my solution is to use:

```
with  decimal.localcontext():
```

Using this, I can choose a value of precision and all the code below it has the defined precision.

Does someone know something like this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: With some maths skills you rarely actually need arbitrary precision.

Comment: In my case, I need it. I'm trying to calculate the orbit of dynamical systems, so if I have a bad arbitrary precision, I can't calculate a big orbit. :\

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase you're looking for is "arbitrary precision."  And there is a library for that in R, called [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html).